# java reflection accessing private field throwing NoSuchFieldException even the field exist

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class with private field

```
public class HibernateSessionFactoryManager{
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
}
```

Now I want to do unit test of some method using the private field. So I was trying to access the private field using java **reflection**.

```
 try {
        Field field = HibernateSessionFactoryManager.class.getDeclaredField("sessionFactory");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        //field.set
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) field.get(manager);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        System.out.println("no such");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am getting

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: sessionFactory at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1584)
```

I am not able to figure out what mistake im doing. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is 'manager' perhaps an object of a derived class?

Comment: Sorry I was using                                                                          manager = spy(new HibernateSessionFactoryManager()); Mockito is a framework I was using for mocking.

Comment: Is your code being obfuscated when you compile it?

Comment: The mocking framework might be creating a Proxy object rather than real object. Check Mockito documentation.

Comment: Yes,Mockito injected the problem, once I removed spy and created actual object, issue got resolved.

Answer (score 3):

For the benefit of those who encounter a similar issue with Mockito: When setting a private field using `class.getDeclaredField()`, the object of which private field is to be set, must be instantiated directly using `new`, not by calling Mockito's `mock()`.